# MongoDB : How to pick with $lte/lt all the documents that answer to specific $sum condition?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Consider :

```
 EightWeekGamePlan.aggregate(
    [
      { $match: { LeadId: { $in: leads }, Week: week, 
          // total: { $lt: 5 } // This part doesn't work
        } },
      {
        $group: {
          _id: {
            LeadId: "$LeadId",
            total: { $sum: "$TotalClaimsLeftToBeClaimedByClientType" }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
```

How can I pick all the documents that their sum of `$TotalClaimsLeftToBeClaimedByClientType` is less than `5` ?

I've tried with `total: { $lt: 5 }`but I got an empty array.

Here is the Schema :

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const EightWeekGamePlanSchema = new Schema({
  Week: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
  LeadId: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  PackageId: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  BusinessName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  PhoneNumberMasque: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  City: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  Rooms: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
  LeadStartDate: {
    type: Date
  },
  LeadEndDate: {
    type: Date
  },

  TargetedToBeClaimedByClientType: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
  TotalClaimsLeftToBeClaimedByClientType: {
    // incresed by 1 every time it's claimed
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
  TotalClaimsToBeClaimedByClientType: {
    // Stays fixed
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
  Status: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },

  InsertDate: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});

module.exports = EightWeekGamePlan = mongoose.model(
  "eightweekgameplan",
  EightWeekGamePlanSchema
);
```

Comment: Can you post sample data? `$group` shouldn't be before `$match`?

Comment: @Valijon: I've added the Schema , and to your question : yes , partially , since first I need to match all the documents that : `1)` answer to a specific week and `2)` contained in an array.After that I want to filter all those that their `total` is less than `5`

Comment: Another `$match` after the group stage should work?.. `$match : {total: { $lt: 5 }}`

Comment: @ambianBeing: Doesn't work

Comment: As you see, `total` field doesn't exists in your scheme (before `$group`), so you cannot filter with "non-existing" field. Switch `$group` and `$match` stages and enable `total` filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your query, try this :

```
EightWeekGamePlan.aggregate(
    [
        {
            $match: {
                LeadId: { $in: leads }, Week: week
            }
        },
        {
            $group: {
                _id: {
                    LeadId: "$LeadId",
                    total: { $sum: "$TotalClaimsLeftToBeClaimedByClientType" }
                }
            }
        }, {
            $match: {
                 '_id.total': { $lte: 5 }
            }
        }
    ])
```

From the above it `$match` did not work because your `total` is not a top level field, it's inside `_id`. So it's basically grouped based on `LeadId + sum of TotalClaimsLeftToBeClaimedByClientType`. Just in case if you wanted to group only based on `LeadId` check below one.

*(Or)* you can change the query :

```
EightWeekGamePlan.aggregate(
    [
        {
            $match: {
                LeadId: { $in: leads }, Week: week
            }
        },
        {
            $group: {
                _id: {
                    LeadId: "$LeadId"
                },
                total: { $sum: "$TotalClaimsLeftToBeClaimedByClientType" }
            }
        }, {
            $match: {
                'total': { $lte: 5 }
            }
        }
    ])
```